# pdf form data extraction with pypdf : how to get only key+values?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, field, pypdf

I'm not a python guru (lire used to R).

I use pypdf package (v3.4.1) to extract data from a pdf form I have created and filled with acrobat.

I can read the form fields with

```
f = PdfReader('test_formulaire.pdf')
ffields = f.get_fields()
```

ffields is a dict object of size 3 (3 keys : 'a1','a2','a5'). Each "key" of the dict is a Field class object.

I can access the value of a key with `print(ffields['a1'].value)`

I now want to create a pandas dataframe with a column for each key of ffields (3 columns, named with the key name) and a row containing the values of each key...

Is there a quick and easy way to do it ?

I can create an empty dataframe with the column names with something like that (probably far from optimal) :

```
column_names = ["" for x in range(len(ffields))]
idx=0
for i in ffields:
    column_names[idx]=i
    idx+=1

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

An filling it should be possible with other for loops but it seems ugly... (note that some values are numbers and other are strings).

Does anybody have a hint for doing this quite efficiently.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm quite stupid... All the fields are strings (I will then transform the dataframe columns that requires it to numbers)

Comment: Have you tried just **`data = pd.DataFrame([ffields])`** or `data = pd.DataFrame({k: [v] for k, v in ffields.items()})` or *`data = pd.DataFrame(data=[ffields.values()], columns=ffields.keys())`* ? They should all [produce the same DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhG4l.png). [also btw, you could have gotten *`column_names`* with just `list(ffields.keys())` and `[""]*3` would return *`["", "", ""]`* ]